# Mailchimp double_optin option not working

Tags: php, arrays, mailchimp

I've followed [this tutorial](http://codeandfun.blogspot.be/2014/02/mailchimp-api-subscribe-user-email.html) to implement mailchimp API v2.0 on my website.
It works great, however the **double_optin** option that I wanted to add and set to **false** (so that users don't need to validate their registration via e-mail) doesn't seem to be working. It's like if it was not taken into consideration at all, users still need to validate the registration via e-mail.

Is `'double_optin' => false` placed at the wrong place? I had a look at [mailchimp documentation](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/subscribe.php) but my level in programmation is not good enough to identify what is wrong.
Thanks for your help

```
<?php
$api_key = "12345486-us8";

$list_id = "123";

require('Mailchimp.php');
$Mailchimp = new Mailchimp( $api_key );
$Mailchimp_Lists = new Mailchimp_Lists( $Mailchimp );
$subscriber = $Mailchimp_Lists->subscribe( $list_id, array( 'email' => htmlentities($_POST['email']),'double_optin' => false ) );

if ( ! empty( $subscriber['leid'] ) ) {
   echo "success";
}
else
{
    echo "fail";
}

?>
```

Comment: We'd have to see your actual code to know if it's in the wrong place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this (admittedly unofficial-looking) [Mailchip_Lists documentation](http://www.avignyata.com/fbtesting/mailchimp-api/docs/class-Mailchimp_Lists.html), you'll want to pass `FALSE` as the 5th parameter to [subscribe()](http://www.avignyata.com/fbtesting/mailchimp-api/docs/source-class-Mailchimp_Lists.html#698-735).

Example:

```
$double_optin = FALSE;

$subscriber = $Mailchimp_Lists->subscribe(
    $list_id,
    array('email' => htmlentities($_POST['email'])),
    NULL, // merge_vars
    'html', // email_type
    $double_optin
);
```

Comment: Just a small typo on the last line: "double" instead of "dobule"

Comment: @Greg Ah, yes. Good catch. Fixed it.